# Why is $(element).offset().top == 0 on afterRender?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

When called via `afterRender`, `$(element).offset().top == 0`, however, calling `offset().top` on the element after `applyBindings` results in the (expected) value 80.

Why is the first one not 80?  Is there anyway to find the expected value (80) in `afterRender`?

## Template

```
<div data-bind="foreach: {data: entries, afterRender: render}">
    <div data-bind="text: name, attr: { 'id': name }"> </div>
</div>
```

## Javascript

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.entries = [
        { name: "one" },
        { name: "two"},
        { name: "three"},
        { name: "four"},
        { name: "five"}
    ];
    this.render = function(element, data) {
        if (data.name == "five")
            alert($(element).offset().top);
    }
 };

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
alert($("#five").offset().top);
```

## Example

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3qnc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `element` you're referring to in

```
$(element).offset().top
```

is not actually a DOM object, it's a Knockout object. It contains some other data besides the HTML. The following yields the correct result, because it's referring to the DOM object:

```
this.render = function(element, data) {
    if (data.name == "five") {
        console.log( $('#five').offset().top );
    }
}
```

I haven't used knockout before, so there may be a better way of accessing it, but I found that the object you're trying to access is actually in the element, it's just one level deep in the object, so that the following also works:

```
this.render = function(element, data) {
    if (data.name == "five") {
        console.log( $( element[1] ).offset().top );
    }
}
```

(Note that I'm using `console.log` for cleaner debugging. I prefer to not have all those alerts popping up.)

[Here's the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78hTe/)